# How create new Form object in template?

Tags: java, templates, playframework, twirl

is possible to create new Form object via template?
I need this because I don't want reapeat myself and use partial with fields from form.
It looks like this:

```
@import play.i18n.Messages
@import play.i18n.Lang

@()

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="@routes.UserRegistrationController.completeUserProfile()" method="POST">
            @user._detailsForm(new Form[UserDetails])
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and _detailsForm need param like:

```
@(form: Form[UserDetails])
```

regarding to [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) Form constructor need 4 param, but I have no idea hot to use it.

Passing Form[UserDetails] to my general template is my **plan B**, I am looking here other solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you could try importing play.data.Form and writing @user._detailsForm(Form.form(ClassName.class)). You might need to import ClassName as well.

Comment: scala doesn't have `.class` but I can use `classOf[User]` and it works! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a solution, special thanks for user7197

```
@import play.i18n.Messages
@import play.i18n.Lang
@import play.data.Form

@()

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="@routes.UserRegistrationController.completeUserProfile()" method="POST">
                    @user._detailsForm(Form.form(classOf[UserDetails]))
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```